# Jmeter - how to use Mail Reader sampler user registration and activation key extraction

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, test-plan

my test-plan requires user creation and activation, but for now i am doing it manually
please guide, how to user Jmeter Mail Reader Sampler and how to extract the activation Key form it..

Answer (score 1):

See this link:

http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url

1. configure reader element
2. Use regex to extra the activation url into var
3. replay the var into a http request test element.